# jQuery Mobile get button that opened Popup

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a listview, when I click a link in the listview it launches a popup.  For simplification purposes I have omitted the listview and am starting with just a single button.

I want to retrieve attributes from the button that caused the popup to show, in my example the attribute named `customAttr`. I then want to insert the value into `popupBasic`.

Here is my very basic sample jQuery Mobile code:

```
<a href="#popupBasic" data-rel="popup" customAttr="value">Basic Popup</a>

<div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic">
    <p>This is a completely basic popup, no options set.</p>
</div>
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cPRCU/2/

Normally when I work with jQuery (non-Mobile) I am more involved with the click event/opening of popup's/dialogs.  I would like to be able to read the button that caused the popup to show, how can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding a click handler to the button seems to work. In this handler, modify the popup before it gets shown:

```
$('a[data-rel="popup"]').click(function () {
    var link = $(this);
    var data = link.attr('customAttr')
    var popup = $(link.attr('href')); // assume href attr has form "#id"
    popup.append(($('<p />').text(data)));
});
```

This is a generic handler which supports a page with multiple buttons/popups. If some buttons should not have this behaviour, I would add a class to the desired button, and make the `a[data-rel="popup"]` selector more specific.

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cPRCU/3/

Answer (score 3):

I did it on a listview itself as it would be more useful to you.

### For a ListView

You have to register a click event for the `<a>` tags in your listview as below first.

```
$('#mylist a').bind('click', function(event){
});
```

meanwhile, make sure to store the data inside the anchor tag as below.
`data-customattr` everything is small here.

e.g.

```
<a href="#popupBasic" data-rel="popup" data-customattr="value2" >Basic Popup 2</a>
```

Now you can read the value of `data-customattr` inside the click event as below

```
$(this).data('customattr')
```

Now I assume that you have a id for the `<p>` tag inside the popup. Something as below

```
  <p id="mypopup">This is a completely basic popup, no options set.</p>
```

using the ID you can replace the popup's content.

finally putting all together something like below

```
$('#mylist a').bind('click', function(event){
    console.log($(this).text());
   $('#mypopup').html($(this).data('customattr'));
});
```

Checkout this <kbd>***[live fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gFTzt/5/)***</kbd> for the working example http://jsfiddle.net/gFTzt/5/

### For a button

If you insist on a example using button then declare a button with an ID as below

```
<a href="#popupBasic" data-rel="popup" id="mybutton" data-role="button" data-customattr="button value">button example</a>
```

As mentioned above register a click event and read the `customattr` value.

```
 $('#mybutton').bind('click',function(){
        alert($(this).data('customattr'));
 });
```

Check out this <kbd>***[live fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gFTzt/5/)***</kbd> example for both button and listview http://jsfiddle.net/gFTzt/5/

### using .attr()

Here I've used the `data` to get the value. without data attribute we can directly get the value from the anchor tag as below.

E.g. we have a anchor tag as below.

```
<a href="#popupBasic" customattr="value1">Basic Popup 1</a>
```

we can read the `value1` using the `.attr()` as below.

```
$(this).attr('customattr')
```

Here is a <kbd>**[Live fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mayooresan/wWmLc/)**</kbd> example.

Comment: Nice bro! `.attr()` works with `customattr` if you remove `data-` ;)

Answer (score 0):

I was having a problem getting popups to work but I finally realized that the popup div needs to be inside the page.  My popup was a sibling to the page where the popup link was and was not showing up until I moved it in to be a sibling of the link and child of the page.