# JQM 1.3 handing over parameters

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a JQM app which shows some friends entries in a list view. All I want to do is to show the details of the friends in a details screen. But I really cant figure out how to hand over a kind of parameter to tell the app which details it should load from the server (on AJAX).

What is the best practise for that?

(JQM 1.3 used)

Many Thanks in advance.

Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So when you load the friend list you need to append the friendID or something to the list too. When someone click on the list item, store the friendID to the `sessionStorage` and navigate the user to the details screen.

In the details screen's `pageshow` event pass the friendid which is stored in the sessionStorage to the server and get the details about that specific friend.

[Read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15710642/jquery-mobile-get-button-that-opened-popup/15710972#15710972) to find out how to store and retreive friend id type of hidden data in the listview